# Grounding in Circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, notation, batteries

[image]

The question is to find the current through the 8 Ω resistor. My textbook says that it is 3A as there is 0 potential at points "a" and "b" and thus it must drop by 24 V across the resistor and then from Ohm's Law 24/8 = 3A. However I fail to understand why it must drop by 24V from just the 8 Ω resistor, even though there is grounding at point "a", do I just ignore the other resistors?

(My guess/thinking) What I was thinking was that a-b is considered a closed loop in the circuit and the potential differences must be 0 from The Loop Rule? (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

Another question I have is what happens to the current from the 24V battery at point "a"?
Does it even travel to the trapezoidal region of resistors? Or does it go straight to the ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My textbook says that it is 3A as there is 0 potential at points "a" and "b" and thus it must drop by 24 V across the resistor and then from Ohm's Law 24/8 = 3A.

Your textbook is correct.

> do I just ignore the other resistors?

To find the current through the 8 $\Omega$ resistor, use Kirchhoff's Voltage Law, KVL, around the loop consisting of the battery and the 8 $\Omega$ resistor and ground. The sum of the IR voltage drops must equal the sum of the emfs in the loop. So IR voltage drop must be 24 V. R is 8 $\Omega$, so I must be 3 A.

> what happens to the current from the 24V battery at point "a"? Does it even travel to the trapezoidal region of resistors?

No, apply KVL again in one of the loops consisting of ground at "a", ground at "b", and some branch in the section above the branch with the battery. Again, the sum of the EMFs is equal to the sum of the IR voltage drops. The sum of the EMFs in such a loop is $0$, so the sum of the IR voltage drops must also be $0$. A little more work, and it can be shown that the IR voltage drop through any of the 2 $\Omega$ resistors in that loop is also $0$.

Comment: For your last paragraph, how come the sum of the EMFs in such a loop is 0? I'm not sure if I completely understand as to which loop you are referring to. If I were to pick a loop that contains "a" and "b" would it not also include the battery?

Comment: The loops I am referring to includes "a" -> ground -> "b" -> 2 ohm -> 2 ohm -> ... "a".  They do not include the battery or the 8 ohm resistor.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a convention in schematic drawings that all the points where the ground symbol is placed are connected by wires (or other conductors) that aren't drawn on the diagram. This is meant to keep the drawing from becoming cluttered and make it easier to read (once you're experienced with this convention).

In this drawing you can replace the ground symbols (since there are only two of them) with a wire connecting directly from one to the other.

Now do your loop calculation again, keeping the new connection in mind.